# facebook og:tags are not crawled live

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I added all important the og:-tags to my site and put some variables in them.
Like the (canonical) URL changes like

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://domain.tld/motivation/day/<?php echo $date;?>"/>
```

every day.

"Facebook debugs" crawls the right content (description/image and so on). The embedded share button does not. Even with

```
    <meta property="og:ttl" content="60"/>
```

the sharer does not crawl the live-data. Instead, it uses the last known dataset.

Is there anyway I can force the sharer.php to crawl live data since there is no way to send parameters to the sharer.php anymore?

Comment: You should not try and constantly change the OG meta data for a URL. If you want to share individual pieces of content with individual OG meta data - then you should provide individual URLs to share for each.

Comment: There is a individual URL for every day -> ".../day/2016-07-05". The description and the image are not modified for each URL.

Comment: Well then I don’t see how this is a caching issue at all. // How did you implement the Share button? You would of course need to point it to the “URL of the day” each day.

Comment: I did that like `<meta property="og:url" content="https://domain.tld/motivation/day/<?php echo $date;?>"/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="https://domain.tld/images/output/<?php echo $dailyImage ?>"/>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXX"/>`  The button is directly configured @ [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

Comment: That is meta data, not the Share button code. You need to include the URL you want to share in the button.

Comment: But sharer.php does not accept parameters anymore (exept URL). The URL is passed correctly but the metadata "image"/"description" should be crawled from URL when shared because theres no way to pass this.

Comment: The more you say, the _less_ clear your problem becomes. _Show_ us your actual implementation.